# Eloquent : How to add the "when" condition in a "with" method?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am using Laravel 10.

I have this query, with several "with" methods :

```
return Result::where('school_id', $school->id)
        ->where('user_id', $user->id)
        ->with(['work' => function (Builder $query) use ($school, $request) {
            $query->where('school_id', $school->id)
                ->orderBy('expected_at')
                ->with(['subject' => function (Builder $query) use ($school) {
                    $query->where('school_id', $school->id);
                }])
                ->with(['workType' => function (Builder $query) use ($school) {
                    $query->where('school_id', $school->id);
                }])
                ->with(['classroom' => function (Builder $query) use ($school) {
                    $query->where('school_id', $school->id);
                }])
                ->with('workStatus');
        }])
        ->paginate();
```

This query works fine.

I would like to add a condition in the "with" methods. This condition is not systematic.

I have tried to add the "when" method like that :

```
return Result::where('school_id', $school->id)
        ->where('user_id', $user->id)
        ->with(['work' => function (Builder $query) use ($school, $request) {
            $query->where('school_id', $school->id)
                ->orderBy('expected_at')

                ->when(isset($request['search']), function ($query) use ($request) {
                    return $query->where('title', 'ilike', '%' . $request['search'] . '%');   
                })

                ->with(['subject' => function (Builder $query) use ($school) {
                    $query->where('school_id', $school->id);
                }])
                ->with(['workType' => function (Builder $query) use ($school) {
                    $query->where('school_id', $school->id);
                }])
                ->with(['classroom' => function (Builder $query) use ($school) {
                    $query->where('school_id', $school->id);
                }])
                ->with('workStatus');
        }])
        ->paginate();
```

This query works (there is no error) but does not return the expected result. It looks like the "when" method is not applied.

I tried also to build first a query string, then add the condition "when" after. It is the same.

How to add this kind of condition ? Perhaps not possible and so I must do a "traditional" SQL request ?

Comment: "looks like" how do you define it looks like it hasn't been applied? does dd(isset($request['search']); give a true statement? and what if you do DB::enableQueryLog(); and dd(DB::getQueryLog()); give you the correct query?

Comment: Yes I see the query, and the $request['search'] is not empty. And the query is not the one I except.

Comment: According to the [Conditional Clauses documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queries#conditional-clauses), you don't need a return inside your `when`, just like in `with`

Comment: i dont have postgres but following query in my example project: Store::with(['company' => function($query) {$query->when(true, function ($query) { $query->where('id', 'like', 42);});}])->get(); executed the following query to load the companies select * from `company` where `company`.`id` in (1, 2, 3) and `id` like ?

Comment: @aynber : I already tried with and without the return inside the "when". No effect !

Comment: I've been working on this request for hours! I'm giving up and I'm going to do it with the old fashioned way!

Answer (score 0):

if when function is not working in your case try doing this

```
Result::where('school_id', $school->id)
->where('user_id', $user->id)
->with(['work' => function (Builder $query) use ($school, $request) {
    $query->where('school_id', $school->id)
        ->orderBy('expected_at');

    if (isset($request['search'])) {
        $query->where('title', 'ilike', '%' . $request['search'] . '%');
    }
```

if it works then something is wrong in your using when query.